# Deserialized part data using fastJSON fail

Tags: java, json, fastjson

I want deserialized part data using fastJSON fail.

```
class A {
    public String a;
}
```

The data

```
{"a": "a",
 "b": "b"
}
```

Use

```
A objectA = JSON.parseObject(data, A.class)
```

get objectA, but the field of a is null.

If I fill the class to

```
class A {
    public String a;
    public String b;
}
```

it deserialized Ok.

Comment: What's your version of fastjson? There's a default feature called `com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.Feature.IgnoreNotMatch` since 1.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

`A.a` ?

Are you sure you did 
`A objectA = JSON.parseObject(data, A.class)`

And got `objectA.a` ?

Otherwise your code should work ...

Comment: Yes, if I fill the class to class A { public String a; public String b;}  parse correct.

Answer (score 0):

Both should work. Maybe you should update you fastjson to the latest version.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for your help. You might want to make your answer even better by adding some explanation.